# Applying Linear regression for quadratic function

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am new to machine learning. For a sample formula , y= 5 + 10(x^2), I generated x and y values and applied linear regression for it. The theta1 and theta2 values I received was for a straight line with large cost. How do I modify linear regression algorithm to get the exact values of theta1 = 5 and theta2 = 10?

Comment: Not Clear!!! Can you put more light??

Comment: In short, if I have a dataset which represents a quadratic equation, how do I get the coefficients of x^2 using linear regression.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more..how do I get the let loss function and apply to linear regression?

Comment: It is basically a approach. Here you know that data follow quadratic equation but in real cases we are unaware that which polynomial equation to use. So we usually use  a one degree line equation and try to fit the data in that line by Linear regression. Basically `hypothesis` have some difference from actual equation therefore we take a distance b/w actual & predicted & try to reduce that is `Loss function` which we usually is square of difference b/w actual & predicted y.

Comment: Thanks, I  think I got the answer. As long as I have the hypothesis evaluated inside the linear regression which is a quadratic or polynomial -equation, we should be able to get the coefficients back correctly